# Persons Matching program or algorithm

Tags: python, excel, algorithm, matching

In a networking event there is a pool of persons. Each person should meet all other persons in a 5 person setting for 10 minutes.

> For example if the pool is having 60 persons. Each person should meet other 4 persons in the same table for 10 minutes. after some time this person should have met all other 59 persons.

Is there any ready-made algorithm/program in Python or Excel that one can input the pool and have the output as a list of 5 persons-lists that is satisfy the condition: each person has met the whole pool with minimal repetitions?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is no general algorithm for this.

As https://www.dmgordon.org/cover/ explains, this is called a covering design.  Optimal covering designs for the problem you are interested in, 5 element sets covering all 2 element sets, are known for many number of vertices, `v`.  See https://ljcr.dmgordon.org/cover.php?vopt=%3C%3D&v=100&kopt=%3D&k=5&topt=%3D&t=2&sizeopt=%3D&size=&creator=&method=&time=A&submit=search for a list, and when they were discovered.  The variety of different sources for that list, including papers within the last 20 years, should demonstrate that this is a hard problem in general.